# can I send Criteria in a spring feign client GetMapping request?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, criteria, feign

I'm trying to get userConfig from `Organisation` microservice, the app is getting quite large to I had too fetch `UserConfig` with `userConfigCriteria` for further use,
I wrote my feign service like this:

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "organization")
@Service
public interface UserConfigFeignService {
    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/api/feign-user-configs",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json",
        method = RequestMethod.GET
    )
    ResponseEntity<List<UserConfigFein>> getUserConfig(UserConfigFeignCriteria criteria);
}
```

implemented like this:

```
public List<UserConfigFein> UserConfigByDepartment(UserConfigFeignCriteria criteria) {
    try {
        return userConfigFeignService.getUserConfig(criteria).getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("feign error: couldn't get all userConfigs with criteria " + criteria);
    }
}
```

in the Organisation `microservice` I created this end pt

```
@GetMapping("/feign-user-configs")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserConfigDTO>> getUserConfig(UserConfigCriteria criteria) {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of UserConfigs by criteria: {}", criteria);
 //bla bla code that is not reached
}
```

an error is thrown at this point
`throw new RuntimeException("feign error: couldn't get all userConfigs with criteria " + criteria);`

```
[405 Method Not Allowed] during [GET] to [http://organization/api/feign-user-configs] [UserConfigFeignService#getUserConfigByDepartmentId(UserConfigFeignCriteria)]: [{
  "title" : "Method Not Allowed",
  "status" : 405,
  "detail" : "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path" : "/api/feign-user-configs",
  "message" : "error.http.405"
}]
```

the end point in `Organization` is not being reached.
any ideas ?

I'm expecting
`UserConfigFeignCriteria`
to be sent to `Organisation` microservice

edit: here's UserConfigFeignCriteria

```
@ParameterObject
public class UserConfigFeignCriteria implements Serializable, Criteria {

    private LongFilter id;
    private StringFilter userId;
    private StringFilter nickname;
    private Boolean focusMode;

    private LongFilter departmentId;
    private Boolean distinct;

    public UserConfigFeignCriteria(UserConfigFeignCriteria other) {
        this.id = other.id == null ? null : other.id.copy();
        this.userId = other.userId == null ? null : other.userId.copy();
        this.nickname = other.nickname == null ? null : other.nickname.copy();
        this.focusMode = other.focusMode;
        this.distinct = other.distinct;
    }

    public UserConfigFeignCriteria() {}

    @Override
    public UserConfigFeignCriteria copy() {
        return new UserConfigFeignCriteria(this);
    }

//getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) 
    @Override
    public int hashCode()

    @Override
    public String toString() 

}
```

Comment: Please post code of UserConfigFeignCriteria

Comment: Please post the testing code

Comment: Also I want to see your blabla code it may have an issue

Comment: @Mohammed Housseyn Taleb, the blabla code is just passing the criteria to a query service but break points are not reached in getUserConfig() anyways

Comment: @Gaël Marziou post edited

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the request method in interface UserConfigFeignService to POST like so

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "organization")
@Service
public interface UserConfigFeignService {
    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/api/feign-user-configs",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json",
        method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    ResponseEntity<List<UserConfigFein>> getUserConfig(UserConfigFeignCriteria criteria);
}
```

I have to make more research for why criteria can not be sent with a get method when using feign client, cause fetching data with POST methos is not a good solution.